# TweepError: [{u'message': u'SSL is required', u'code': 92}]

Tags: python

Here is my python script to fetch the tweets from my account

```
import tweepy

consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""
access_token=""
acces_token_secret=""
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api.tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
   print tweet.text
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\enter code herePython27\twitter_api.py", line 16, in <module>
    public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 185, in _call
    return method.execute()

File "build\bdist.win32\egg\tweepy\binder.py", line 168, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)

TweepError: [{u'message': u'SSL is required', u'code': 92}]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, secure=True)
```